# How much physical damage does dropping electronic devices cause?

Tags: portable

Phones iPads and other modern portable electronics get dropped. Before the screen is broken and damage becomes physically visible beyond a warp in the entire device structure, How much damage is done to the internal circuitry? 
What percentage of software errors could be responsible for non-localized damage?

Comment: Unlikely any 'software errors' would occur. If the BGA package soldering is damaged, mechanical intermittent memory errors could occur. This can also happen from vibration, temperature cycling etc. and not just shock.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany aye am i right to say the user would see apps crash for os and application errors caused by the memory errors

Comment: It's possible- likely they would be visibly correlated with ambient temperature, internal temperature and/or physical shaking (mechanically intermittent).

Comment: Depending on how the PCB is mounted in a case, it may flex enough to break some traces, either n the top or bottom, or in the interior.  It's possible (but unlikely) that large surface mount components could be dislodged from the PCB, maybe even pulling traces off of the board with them.  Ribbon cables may come loose from their connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, fall damage is almost always visible (i.e. cracks on the case, broken displays etc). Since typical fall distance is about 1m, the shock is not even nearly enough to break PCB traces (that would actually require a hammer) or dislodge a typical IC component.

Sometimes components do get dislodged in particularly bad PCB designs - often with surface-mountable components with small pads and important mass (like coils). Good designs tend to use bigger pads, pins going through the PCB and/or glue to avoid such issues.

If several PCBs are connected inside a device with rigid connectors, those will be the first to go as well. This is often the case with cameras, but you usually won't notice it since the optics will not survive the fall anyway. Flexible connectors like ribbon cables will, oh well, *flex*, so little stress will be applied to the connector itself.

Another weak point is moving elements located in corners or beyond device's outline (volume wheels, buttons etc.) If such elements are the first to hit the floor, they will absorb most of the shock and won't survive.

BGA packages rarely get damaged by falls. They are usually quite lightweight, and the stress from the shock is distributed to hundreds of pins. BGA soldering does get damaged quite often though, because of thermal deformation, as such components tend to dissipate a fair amount of power.